# pandas rename columns then assign to a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

python 2.7 - I want to create a new dataframe with renaming columns from a different dataframe

for example x is a pandas DF and I want to rename the columns and save it into y

this example returns NONE

```
x=pd.read_excel(r'C:\hm.xlsx')
y=x.rename(columns={'Zip': 'Zipcode'},inplace='False')
print y
```

however if I do

```
x=pd.read_excel(r'C:\hm.xlsx')
x.rename(columns={'Zip': 'Zipcode'},inplace='True')
print x
```

this correctly renames it -- what do I need to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This

```
x = pd.read_excel(r'C:\hm.xlsx')
y = x.copy()
y.rename(columns={'Zip': 'Zipcode'},inplace='True')
print(y)
```

x.rename() is a function that does not return anything but rather alters x. 
By setting `y = x.rename()` you are therefore setting y to NoneType.
`y = x.copy()` is necessary to create a deep copy rather than a pointer to x, so you can alter y without altering x

Comment: totally - they are making me wait 5 min though. so will do shortly